# 'The database engine could not lock table' in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, office-2016

I have a function that allows users to efectivly TRUNCATE an Access table.

It's a fairly basic function; it deletes all rows, and then resets the auto-increment index by changing the data-type of the ID column to `INT`, and then back to `AUTOINCREMENT`.

However, I'm running in to a problem; on occasion, when a user presses a button that calls the function, I'm halted by an error -

> The database engine could not lock table 'Active Directory' because it is already in use by another person or process.

**This error does not occur every time, but once it appears, I have to close Access to make it go away.**

The error occurs on this line -

```
DB.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & tableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [ID] INT"
```

There table in question is abslolutly not open with Access, and even closing the table before calling this function does not work -

```
DoCmd.Close acTable, tableName, acSaveYes
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this error and get my code working as I require?

```
Function Truncate(ByVal tableName As String, Optional ByVal resetIndex As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo checkResult   ' Set up error handling

    Call Functions.setWarnings(False)    ' Disable warnings

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Set DB = CurrentDb  ' Set the DB object to use

    '**
     ' Clear the table contents
     '*
    DB.Execute "DELETE * FROM [" & tableName & "]"

    '**
     ' Change the data type of the ID field to INT
     '*
    DB.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & tableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [ID] INT"

    '**
     ' Change the data type of the ID field back to AUTOINCREMENT
    DB.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & tableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [ID] AUTOINCREMENT"

    '**
     ' Check the result of the TRUNCATE operation
     '*
checkResult:
    Call Functions.setWarnings(True)            ' Enable warnings
    Truncate = IIf(Err.Number = 0, True, False) ' Set the result

End Function
```

Comment: Google found this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21538158/Delete-table-but-The-database-engine-could-not-lock-table-'tblHibo456'-because-it-is-already-in-use-by-another-person-or-process.html

Comment: I'm not a member of Experts Exchange so cannot view verified answers.

Comment: I'm not either, but they say something about closing the record set that you might try.  I'd recommend getting a real relational database instead of Access and a real language besides VB.

Comment: @HansUp - I currently have only one form open (no reports/tables/queries), and that form basically calls the above function on click, and then displays a success/fail message based on the result.

Comment: @HansUp - `setWarnings(False)` does include `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` (as well as a couple of other bits).  I've tried excluding that from the code, but error still occurs.

Comment: @HansUp - Ignore my previous comment.  I had a ListBox on a form that queries a field on the "Active Directory" table and forgot all about it.  The form wasn't visible, but obviously still had the table locked from when I had used it.  I've added a line to the above function to ensure that the offending form is closed and so far, so good.

Comment: @HansUp - Thanks, I'll give that a try in a moment.  Sadly the reset of the auto-increment is a scoped requirement of the project, I have to do it despite my objections.